# Performance issues with AVMutableComposition - scaleTimeRange

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I am using `scaleTimeRange:toDuration:` to produce a fast-motion effect of upto 10x the original video speed.But I noticed that videos start to stutter when played through an AVPlayer at 10x.

I also noticed that on OSX's QuickTime the same composition plays smoothly.

Another question states that the reason for this is hardware limitation , but I want to know if there is a way around this , so that the fast motion effect occurs smoothly over the length of the entire video.

**Video Specs**

- *Format*       : H.264 , 1280x544
- *FPS*          : 25
- *Data Size*    : 26MB
- *Data Rate*    : 1.17 Mbit/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that by playing your videos at 10x using  `scaleTimeRange:toDuration` simply has the effect of multiplying your data rate by 10, bringing it up to 10Mbit/s, which osx machines can handle, but iOS devices cannot.

In other words, you're creating videos that need to play back at 300 frames per second, which is pushing `AVPlayer` too hard.

If I didn't know about your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42481763/22147), I would have said that the solution is to export your `AVComposition` using `AVAssetExportSession`, which should result in your high FPS video being down sampled to an easier to handle 30fps, and then play that with `AVPlayer`.

If `AVAssetExportSession` isn't working, you could try applying the speedup effect yourself, by reading the frames from the source video using `AVAssetReader` and writing every tenth frame to the output file using `AVAssetWriter` (don't forget to set the correct presentation timestamps).